# How do you show this multivariable function is injective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> How do I show the function $f(x,y,z)=(x^{2}-y^{2},xy,xz,yz)$ is injective?

I have been trying to use algebra to show it is injective (as in, each point is an antipodal point in $S^{2}$).

So far, if $(x^{2}-y^{2},xy,xz,yz)=(x'^{2}-y'^{2},x'y',x'z',y'z')$, I get $\frac{y}{y'}=\frac{x}{x'}=\frac{z'}{z}$. I tried to make a system for the first two equalities, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any hints or tips are appreciated!

Comment: Injective over $\Bbb R^3$ or over $S^2$ only?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its injective, not even on $S^2$. Consider the points $p=(1, 0, 0)$, $q=(-1, 0, 0)$. Then, $f(p)=f(q)=(1, 0, 0, 0)$.

To address your additional question:
$f(0,0,c)=(0,0,0,0)$ for all $c\in \mathbb R$. So this also isn't correct.

Comment: You mean $...=(1,0,0,0)$ ?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts sure. Also corrected it already. Is it still displayed wrong?

Comment: No, all fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually trying to show that if $f(p)=f(q)$, then either $p=q$ or $p=-q$.

Comment: That isn't injective... Should probably update the question to reflect that.

Comment: As a sidenote, we can know $\lvert x \rvert, \lvert y \rvert, \lvert z \rvert$ but never the signs. 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b c}{d} = (xy)(xz)/(yz) = x^2 \\
\frac{b  d}{c} = (xy)(yz)/(xz) = y^2 \\
\frac{c d}{b} = (xz)(yz)/(xy) = z^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @numericalorange This also isn't correct, see the expanded answer.